# jOOQ addConditions: in SQL question mark appears instead of the value

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I would like to launch simple code:

```
SelectQuery query = dsl.select(field ("id"), field("title")).from("dict.models").getQuery();
if (modelId > 0) query.addConditions(field("model_id", SQLDataType.INTEGER).equal(modelId));
```

But infortunately in `getSQL()` I can only see:

```
select id, title from dict.models where model_id = ?
```

Where is a mistake?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`Query.getSQL()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Query.html#getSQL--) generates the SQL statement as it would be generated if you let jOOQ execute a `PreparedStatement` - with bind variables. The bind variables can be extracted in the right order via [`Query.getBindValues()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Query.html#getBindValues--)

If you want to inline all bind values into the generated SQL, you have various options through the jOOQ API (all equivalent):

- Using [`Query.getSQL(ParamType)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Query.html#getSQL-org.jooq.conf.ParamType-) with `ParamType.INLINE`
- Using [`dsl.renderInlined(QueryPart)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#renderInlined-org.jooq.QueryPart-)
- Using [`StatementType.STATIC_STATEMENT`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/conf/StatementType.html#STATIC_STATEMENT) in your [`Settings`](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/custom-settings/)