# JOOQ: 3.10.5 concat string value with field

Tags: concatenation, jooq

I'm new to JOOQ and using the latest version of JOOQ (3.10.5). 
I am using it just as a SQL builder and not executing it against any DB.

I created the DSLContext using

```
Connection creatorConn = null;

creator = DSL.using(creatorConn, SQLDialect.MYSQL_8_0);
```

When i tried to concat an arbitrary String 'CC_' with a qualified field name field("TBL.[COLUMN NAME]") then resulting field is like

```
'CC'_ || "TBL.[COLUMN NAME]"
```

Then, when i use getSQL(), i got something like

```
select concat(?, TBL.[COLUMN NAME])
```

Can someone please tell me what went wrong and why is it the string concatenated has been replaced with a ?.

Answer (score 1):

As per the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26809490/jooq-addconditions-in-sql-question-mark-appears-instead-of-the-value) by [Lukas Eder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/521799/lukas-eder)

I just added the

> ParamType.INLINED to the Query.getSQL()

method which resolved this issue. Thanks